# What's the purpose of .firebase/hosting. ALPHANUM.cache

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

Today I deployed firebase hosting. After deployment, I noticed firebase creates file of `.firebase/hosting.ALPHANUM.cache`, where ALPHANUM is actually some random baseNN ish value.

#### Question

- What is the purpose of this file?
- More especially, can I add this to `.gitignore`?

  - Or, I should not?

Comment: Not sure what this specific file is for, and I can't find it on my system. But you'll usually want to add all `.` files (so `.firebase/*`) to your `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

This file is part of a new feature in Firebase Hosting that minimizes the size the time of a hosting deployment by only uploading the files that changed since the last deployment.  It's new in CLI version 4.2.0, and you can [read about that on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v4.2.0).

As Frank suggested, you should definitely add the `.firebase` directory to your .gitignore or equivalent file, since it contains information that's not strictly part of your project, and is likely not applicable for everyone sharing and contributing to your project source code.

Comment: For those who want to remove the `.firebase` directory from git tracking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19095988/3414529