# Should we (git / version control) track .firebase folder for Firebase Hosting?

Tags: git, firebase, flutter, version-control, firebase-hosting

I have hosted my Flutter app using Firebase Hosting. After hosting it, I noticed that a `.firebase` folder was created that contains just one file, `hosting.<alphanumeric>.cache`.

Should I track the contents of the `.firebase` folder? Or should I add the `.firebase` folder to the `.gitignore`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131191: Quote, "you should definitely add the `.firebase` directory to your .gitignore or equivalent file, since it contains information that's not strictly part of your project, and is likely not applicable for everyone sharing and contributing to your project source code."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is there to make your hosting deplyoment faster. It is used to check if files have changed since the last deployment.

It is recommended to put it to your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I'm sorry but who "recommended" it? You have to cite your sources.